# Failed to resolve: support-compat react native video

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to install react-native-video on a fresh project but after linking the library, i got this error:

```
    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native- 
    video:debugCompileClasspath'.
    > Could not find support-compat.jar (com.android.support:support- 
    compat:27.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
     https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support- 
     compat/27.1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.jar
```

I've tried all the ways those mentioned in similar topics but no luck
react-native version: 0.57.8
react-native-video version: 4
android studio: 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

For temporary solution, i installed react-native-video version:3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

node module
inside
react-native-video

update from 2.13.2  to 2.13.3

implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.13.3') {

[image]